# How to get Vertica-Kafka scheduler to work with Avro schema registry?

Tags: apache-kafka, vertica, confluent-schema-registry

how to set up Vertica scheduler for consuming Avro data from Kafka

Hi I’m trying to use Vertica Scheduler to consume Avro data from Kafka topic.
I wrote a small java code that produces a simple objects as Avro data into Kafka.
I also pushed the schema into kafka-schema-registry and I can see it from the browser.
I'm trying to set up a Vertica's scheduler, all the commands are passed without errors.
I also launched a micro batch, but the table is empty and my  scheduler doesn't consume data from Kafka topic
first I configured a conf file named schduler.properties:

`config-schema=person100_sched
username=dbadmin
dbhost=10.50.50.16
dbport=5433`

than on Vertica DB I created a resource pool

`CREATE RESOURCE POOL person100_pool MEMORYSIZE '10%' PLANNEDCONCURRENCY 1 QUEUETIMEOUT 0;`

my next step is  creating a scheduler:

`sudo ./vkconfig scheduler --create   --operator dbadmin --frame-duration '00:00:02' --resource-pool person100_pool  --conf scheduler.properties`

my next step is create a cluster

`sudo ./vkconfig cluster --create  --cluster person100_cluster --hosts kafka:9092 --conf scheduler.properties`

my next step is create a source:

`sudo ./vkconfig source --create --cluster person100_cluster  --source person-avro --partitions 1 --conf  scheduler.properties`

my next step is creating a target table:

`sudo ./vkconfig target --create --target-schema public --target-table person100 --conf scheduler.properties`

- Then I created a table in Vertica with same types as Person schema

my next is create an AvroParser

`sudo ./vkconfig load-spec --create --parser KafkaAvroParser --load-spec person_load --conf  scheduler.properties`

my next step is create microbatch

`sudo ./vkconfig microbatch --create --microbatch personBatch --target-schema public --target-table person100   --load-spec person_load  --add-source person-avro --add-source-cluster person100_cluster      --conf scheduler.properties`

my next step is launch the microbatch

`sudo ./vkconfig launch --conf  scheduler.properties`

looks like everything goes well, but the table is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create your `load-spec` you need to specify the schema registry options Vertica will use to parse the Avro messages.

```
--parser-parameters "schema_registry_url='schema-registry:8081',schema_registry_subject='somesubject',schema_registry_version='1',flatten_arrays=TRUE,flatten_maps=TRUE,flatten_records=TRUE"
```

Instead of `schema-registry:8081` and `somesubject` use the same information you used to connect to the schema-registry in your browser.

**Note:** If the table `person100` is not a flex table, then you will need to include, `flatten_arrays=TRUE,flatten_maps=TRUE,flatten_records=TRUE` in addition to the schema registry information.

The full command to create the load-spec should look something like this.

```
sudo ./vkconfig load-spec --create --parser KafkaAvroParser --load-spec person_load --parser-parameters "schema_registry_url='schema-registry:8081',schema_registry_subject='somesubject',schema_registry_version='1',flatten_arrays=TRUE,flatten_maps=TRUE,flatten_records=TRUE" --conf scheduler.properties
```

Comment: Glad to hear it. If you're satisfied with the answer and explanation, can you mark the question answered? Thanks!